# searching github by organization or user

Tags: github

There are 42 repositories on https://github.com/FreeUnityProjects

[image]

But when I search via the API and even the web interface for repositories (org:FreeUnityProjects), I'm only see 18.

https://github.com/search?q=org%3AFreeUnityProjects

[image]

All the repositories are public, and I think were created the same way.  I've tried searching by user as well.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that searching by org isn't showing forks, the answer is to add fork:true to the search:

https://github.com/search?q=org%3AFreeUnityProjects+fork%3Atrue